# What is the correct placement, in an url, of a #bookmark and ?parameters?

Tags: http

Is it

```
url?params#bookmark, e.g. google.com?search=blahblah#bookmark
```

or

```
url#bookmark?Params
```

Have tried both and they work, but I'm wondering if there is a "correct" way to do this?

Comment: Isn't using Google much faster and simpler than creating a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Ironically this Q&A is the first result returned by Google on the topic for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to ask about something you would find on the [first result returned by Google](https://www.google.cz/search?q=url)?

Check [Wikipedia article about URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator):

```
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```

Or [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]


     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

Comment: believe it or not, it never occurred to me to search just "url".

Comment: Wait. Sorry, no offence, but how do you want to do coding, if you don't know how to find information. If I don't know the format of URL, I search for "URL" or "URL format". If I don't know how to use function `Foo()` or object `Bar`, I search for "function Foo" or "object Bar". It can't be easier with today's internet and search engines.

Comment: David (https://stackoverflow.com/users/971141/david-ferenczy-rogo%c5%bean), I much enjoy and glean knowledge more efficiently from StackOverflow and don't mind folks asking simple questions here in order to get a more excellent and searchable answers from our polite and helpful membership.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use `#` or `?` depends on what you're trying to achieve.

### Example 1

I have an article I want to share with my friends & when the user lands on the page, I would like the page to be scrolled automatically to the Introduction section.  The `#` symbol works great for that:

- website.com/article1#introduction
- `<a href="website.com/article1#introduction>`

Typically, the hash `#` symbol is used for linking to a section of a page with an anchor tag `<a href="website.com/article1#introduction>`

### Example 2

If you are implementing a REST like API and are using the URL to store state or fetch data then `?` is the approach to take.

```
/map?state=California&city=Oakland
```

There are native browser APIs (*nodeJS / Deno..other Javascript runtimes etc*)  that provide you several APIs for manipulating & extracting information from a URL using the `?` param syntax.
- [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)
- [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)